# Facebook login using Xamarin.iOS and Azure - 'Resource not found'

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm following the example [Xamarin.iOS Azure Facebook](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure/), and the implementation **works fine on Android**. It's not using facebook sdk, but opening the default webview. This is provided by the Azure.Mobile.Client SDK.

So... when running the 'same' application on iOS, an error appears before reaching the login view

'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable'

The online platform specific code in the iOS project is exactly what comes from the documentation (link above):

```
user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync (
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController,
MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
```

In my solution this line looks like this:

```
var user = await _client.MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
```

I'm running on iOS 10.2, using VisualStudio 2017 Pro.

You can see the whole solution on [github](https://github.com/StefanRiedmann/CicloGardens)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I'm sorry, but looks like it was just too late for programming last night. The error was so obvious:

Instead of 'Facebook', I tried to authenticate against 'Google', because of copy&paste and being inattentive...

```
var user = await _client.MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindowRootViewController,MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```